# How do I filter entire object in searchBar

Tags: swift, xcode, filtering, uisearchbar

In my `Xcode` project I have a `tableView` with a `list` of data. I have implemented a `searchBar` to filter user input. I would like it to filter my entire object `var contactArray = [ExternalAppContactsBook]()` but for some reason I'm only allowed to filter its properties, like `contactArray.firstName`. Here's what it looks like in `searchbar` function:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {        
    if searchBar.text?.count == 0 {
        isFiltered = false
    }else {
        print("HELLO")
        isFiltered = true

        filteredName = contactArray.filter({$0.firstName.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText})
    }
    tableViewOutlet.reloadData()
}
```

So, instead of `$0.firstName` I would like to have `$0.prefix` but the compiler says that there is no such property.

With `$0.firstName` I can only search first names on the list which is pretty limiting... I'm going about this the right way or what should I do?

***Edit***
ExternalAppContactsBook look like this:

```
class ExternalAppContactsBook {

var firstName = ""
var lastName = ""
var phoneNumber = ""
var company = ""
}
```

I have rewritten my code, but I run into the same problem. This is what I've got now in `searchBar textDidChange`:

```
filteredName = contactArray.filter({ object -> Bool in
    guard let text = searchBar.text else {return false}
    return object.firstName.contains(text)
})
```

This works, but it only works when I search on the first name of the people on the list. I want to be able to search their last names as well.

So I tried adding another one:

```
filteredLastName = contactArray.filter({ object -> Bool in
    guard let text = searchBar.text else {return false}
    return object.lastName.contains(text)
})
```

Then in `cellForRowAt`_

```
 if isFiltered {
        contactName = filteredName[indexPath.row].firstName
        contactLastName = filteredLastName[indexPath.row].lastName
 ...}
```

But this obviously doesn't work and provide a problem with how many `rows` that should be returned in `numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: Can you show the model for ExternalAppContactsBook?

Comment: But what would `prefix` be of your entire object? You could create a computed property that represents the entire object (whatever that means) and filter on that. Another option is to have your class conform to `Equatable` but I am not sure exactly what you are after here. Maybe you could clarify your question with some examples.

Comment: Unrelated but never check with `.count == 0` for an empty string. There is more efficient `if searchText.isEmpty`. And the filter line can be optimized, too: `filteredName = contactArray.filter{$0.firstName.range(of: searchText, options:[.caseInsensitive, .anchored]) != nil}`. As Joakim said you can’t search for multiple properties with a single expression unless you add a computed property.

Comment: @Andrew Sure, see update!

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? you have 4 properties in `ExternalAppContactsBook` and prefix is not one of them so you get that error. so you can add that property and then filter it using `$0.prefix`

Comment: @MohyG See updated answer, I think it makes more sense now that I have updated the code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use a condition with OR (||) when filtering

```
let filteredName = contactArray.filter {$0.firstName.starts(with: searchStr) || $0.lastName.starts(with: searchStr)}
```

You could also add this as a function to your class

```
func isMatch(_ searchString: String) -> Bool {
    return firstName.starts(with: searchString) || lastName.starts(with: searchString)
}
```

And then filter

```
let filteredName = contactArray.filter {$0.isMatch(searchStr)}
```

Comment: I have a minor issue in dealing with blank spaces. For example, I wan't to search for Kate Black. When I have written Kate and press the spacebar the search result disappear. Is there a way to remove sensitivity to blank spaces?

Comment: @WhipperSnapper You can trim spaces using `trimmingCharacters(in:)`, `searchString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)`